# Plotting a number of different sized points

Tags: r, plot

I have following simple data:

```
ddf=structure(list(name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"
), class = "factor"), n = c(5L, 4L, 6L), m = c(10L, 15L, 11L)), .Names = c("name", 
"n", "m"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
> 

> ddf
  name n  m
1    a 5 10
2    b 4 15
3    c 6 11
```

I want to plot like this: the name should be on x-axis. There should be n number of points vertically above the name (like a bar or a column chart but I want points). Hence there should be 5 points above a, 4 above b and 6 above c. These points may be stacked over each other or be jittered. The size of these points should correspond to number in column 'm' (cex=m works for size, but I am unable to plot n number of points). Thanks for your help.

Comment: `with(ddf, plot(unlist(mapply(rep, 1:3, n)), unlist(mapply(':', 1, n)), cex = rep(m / 5, n), xpd = NA))`

Comment: Starting with @rawr's comment, add an `xaxt="n"` after `xpd=NA`. Then run the additional command `axis(side=1,at=1:nrow(ddf),labels=ddf$name)` to get the names on the x axis.

Comment: oh right, forgot that part

Comment: Thanks. It works well but x-axis names are overlapping previous number names.

Comment: thats what the `xaxt = 'n'` was for

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks again. But there are unnecessary x and y-axis titles. But I think I will be able to work it out.